# How do I return an object from another model in a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `Post` model, that has the following columns:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: posts
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  title          :string(255)
#  photo          :string(255)
#  body           :text
#  created_at     :datetime
#  updated_at     :datetime
#  user_id        :integer
#  ancestry       :string(255)
#  file           :string(255)
#  status         :integer          default(0)
#  slug           :string(255)
#  is_published   :integer          default(0)
#  has_eyewitness :boolean          default(FALSE)
```

And a `Post belongs_to :user`.

What I want to do is create a `scope :eyewitness` on `Post`, where whenever `has_eyewitness` is true, it returns the associated `user` record.

I tried doing this:

```
scope :eyewitness, -> { where (has_eyewitness: :true).user }
```

But that gives me all sorts of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be returning a single model instance from a scope, that is not what scopes are for.  Scopes should always be returning `ActiveRecord::Relation` such that other query methods and scopes can be chained.  Read more on [Scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

As scopes are really syntactic sugar for class methods, I would recommend you to use a class method instead as:

```
def self.eyewitness
  where(has_eyewitness: true).first.user
end
```

Note that `where` will return a relation which is why we are calling `first` before calling `user`.

**Edit:** As discussed in comments below, OP was in fact looking for an instance method and not a scope or a class method.  Adding `eyewitness` method in `post` model should resolve the issue:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def eyewitness
    user if has_eyewitness?
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what it is that I want it to do. I end up getting a `NoMethodError: undefined method `eyewitness' for #<Post:0x00000101421c40>`. The reason is because whenever this is run, it is already being run on the object, so ".first" doesn't make sense. What I am trying to do is whenever this method is called, to first check to see if `has_eyewitness :true` and if it is then return the `user` object. If not, then return an error message. How might I achieve this?

Comment: @marcamillion, so what you are saying is this needs to be an instance method not a class method.  Is that correct?  If that's the case I would just define an instance method and return the user if `has_eyewitness` for the particular post is `true`.  I'll update my answer if you could clarify your question.

Comment: Yes I believe that to be the case. If I am not mistaken, all you would have to do is do an if statement and change the name of the class method to be `class eyewitness` right?

Comment: Yes, I also think that is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be either:

```
scope :eyewitness, -> { where (has_eyewitness: true).user }
```

or something like:

```
scope :eyewitness, -> { where (:has_eyewitness => true).user }
```